# jquery addclass to body tag

Tags: jquery, addclass

The following script is within a div, does this matter? As it doesn't work. Is the syntax right? Do I need to tell jquery to go up a level in the DOM first? how would I do this?

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('body').addClass('diary');
        });
```

Thanks guys.

Here is the relevant section in the HTML:

```
<body>
```

```
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>  
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <a class="first" href="http://www.adrianwaddingham.com">HOME</a>
      <a class="second" href="/sheriff">SHERIFF</a>
      <a class="third" href="/biography">BIOGRAPHY</a>
      <a class="fourth" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>     
      <a class="fifth" href="/diary">DIARY</a>     

    </nav>

  </header>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('body').addClass('diary');
        });    
</script>


<section class="copy-main">
  <article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you are viewing the html source to check body class you added. DOM manipulation with javascript is not visible in source code, but you can check it with Developer Tools in your browser(Chrome, Firefox and IE have one).

Comment: Sorry for wasting all your time... didn't know about class not showing in view source. Once I'd verified, I soon found the issue - recently started using SASS and the compiled version of my stylesheet doesn;t automatically upload to the site. thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly correct since `$('body')` will search the whole DOM

Comment: thanks, although when I view source on the page, the body remains without a class.

Comment: There must be another problem. Any errors in the console? Can you show us more code?

Answer (score 1):

No problem with script. `Diary` class will apply to body. Can you share you diary class and please check that `jQuery` is loaded correctly, use any development tool like firebug.

Add jQuery file in your page like following where Scripts is folder and `jQuery.js` is jQuery file. If you already included this in your page then check with any developer tool that it is loading correctly.

```
<script src="Scripts/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or add from CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: body.diary a{
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;

}

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Check here, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/P5uS2/. Use FireBug or Chrome Inspector to check the `<body>` tag.

Make sure you included `jquery` file.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check jquery is being loaded? I have the link in there.

Comment: Check page source or view source on your browser. Look for jquery.js or jquery.min.js